# Kendo UI Angular Dialog - Custom Dialog Width

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

How do i set the width of a custom dialog box?

I tried setting the width of the div but that made no difference.

Any help?

Note: I dont use the `<kendo-dialog></kendo-dialog>` tags as it is a custom dialog

Code:

```
<template #itemListRef>
    <casts></casts>
</template>
<button (click)="showConfirmation(itemListRef)" class="k-button">Please confirm</button>
<div kendoDialogContainer></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Directive Answer:**

It doesn't look like there's an option to pass width into the dialog service. See the file `kendo-angular-dialog\dist\npm\dialog.service.js` in your node_modules.

This means that you'd have to use Global CSS to style the width of the box. You could use the a class on the selector which has the directive attached to specify this:

HTML

```
<div class="dialog600">
    <div kendoDialogContainer></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dialog600 .k-dialog {width: 600px}
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HujfFK3FVDhLNlmRaLwt?p=preview)**

---

**Old Answer, assumed component used:**

You can simply use the `[width]` input on the selector.

e.g.

```
<kendo-dialog [width]=1000>...</kendo-dialog>
```

This would set the dialog box to 1000px wide.

Note, however, that this effectively sets the `max-width` of the dialog box - the dialog box won't spill outside the window. The `min-width` of the dialog box is also styled to 450px, as set inside the main selector with the `.k-dialog` tag:

[image: k-dialog width]

If you're trying to go smaller than 450px, you'll have to set the overwrite the `min-width` with your own styling.

Comment: Im not using the kendo-dialog tag, its a custom dialog

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Would you be able to add the code you're using in the original question? I presume it's using the service or directive?

Comment: Where have you added the CSS?

Comment: in my .css file

Comment: Which one? If it's in the components CSS file then it won't bind. You need to use a Globally used one, like the style tag in the index.html.

Comment: its a global css file

Comment: Have you tried it in the same way as the Plunker in the answer above?

Comment: I put it in a style sheet `app.component.css`

Comment: Those styles will bind to app.component.ts's HTML, but not the rest of the project.

The style needs to be added to a Global sheet - I don't know how your project is laid out or being built, but if you have a "style.css" in the root of a src file then put it there. If not, then you need to provide more details.

Comment: actually you're incorrect, i point each component's styleurl path to that file

Comment: Yes, but those styles will be assigned to actual elements that they find in the template.

Have you added the style to the style tag in your index.html or equivalent?

Comment: Depends on your build.

As we have no information about your project, I'm gonna leave this here. Best of luck.